# Java- Temperature conversion loop issue

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement, methods

I'm doing small exercise on java Programming.

Basically the application allows the user to enter a Fahrenheit temperature and displays the Celsius equivalent or enter a Celsius temperature and displays the Fahrenheit equivalent.
The application includes a Celsius method which returns the Celsius equivalent of a Fahrenheit temperature. The application also include a Fahrenheit method, which returns the Fahrenheit equivalent of a Celsius temperature.

Here's my full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature{

    public static void main(String[] args) {  // Main Method//

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare variables
        int choice; // the user's choice in the menu //
        int temp;   

        do   {

             // print the menu

                System.out.println("1.fahrenheit to Celsius"); 
                System.out.println("2.Celsius to Fahrenheit"); 
                System.out.println("3.Exit"); 
                System.out.println(""); 
                System.out.println("Choice:");

             choice = input.nextInt();


             if  ( choice != 3 ) {

         System.out.print( "Enter temperature: " ); // Display Enter Temperature
         temp = input.nextInt();  // Read Temperature


         if (choice == 1) {

             System.out.println( temp +  " Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius( temp ) + " Celsius ");
             System.out.println("");
         }

         else if (choice == 2 ) {
             System.out.println(temp + " Celsius is " +  toFahrenheit( temp ) + " Fahrenheit ");
             System.out.println("");

          } 

         else {
             System.out.println("Program terminated ");   //  Display "Program terminated" if user entered 3
             }

        }  //end if loop

        } // end do loop
        while (choice !=3);

    }  // end main method



    // return Celsius equivalent of Fahrenheit temperature
         public static int    toCelsius(int  fahrenheit) {
             int   celsius;
             celsius = (int) (5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32));
             return celsius;
           }  // end method celsius


         // return Fahrenheit equivalent of Celsius temperature
         public static int    toFahrenheit(int  celsius) {
             int   fahrenheit;
              fahrenheit = (int) (9.0/5.0 * celsius + 32);
             return fahrenheit;
           } // end method fahrenheit



    }
```

Good thing is that the code including the methods are working.The User can either enter choice 1 or 2  and then enter temperature number and display it in Celsius or Fahrenheit. But if the user enter choice 3, the program will display 'Program terminated'. For me, when I entered  choice 3, The program stopped working (Did not display 'Program terminated'). I think there's a problem on the 'loop' part or the 'IF' part.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included everything in if(choice!=3) so even if you enter choice as 3 then also the else including Program terminated won't run. So just re-organize the parenthesis and everything will work fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature{

   public static void main(String[] args) {  // Main Method//

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Declare variables
       int choice; // the user's choice in the menu //
       int temp;   

       do   {

            // print the menu

               System.out.println("1.fahrenheit to Celsius"); 
               System.out.println("2.Celsius to Fahrenheit"); 
               System.out.println("3.Exit"); 
               System.out.println(""); 
               System.out.println("Choice:");

            choice = input.nextInt();


            if  ( choice != 3 ) {

              System.out.print( "Enter temperature: " ); // Display Enter Temperature
              temp = input.nextInt();  // Read Temperature


              if (choice == 1) {

                  System.out.println( temp +  " Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius( temp ) +" Celsius ");
                  System.out.println("");
              }

              else if (choice == 2 ) {
                  System.out.println(temp + " Celsius is " +  toFahrenheit( temp ) + " Fahrenheit ");
                  System.out.println("");

              } 

            }
            else {
             System.out.println("Program terminated ");   //  Display "Program terminated" if user entered 3
           }//end else loop

       } // end do loop
       while (choice !=3);

   }  // end main method



// return Celsius equivalent of Fahrenheit temperature
   public static int    toCelsius(int  fahrenheit) {
       int   celsius;
       celsius = (int) (5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32));
        return celsius;
   }  // end method celsius


     // return Fahrenheit equivalent of Celsius temperature
     public static int    toFahrenheit(int  celsius) {
         int   fahrenheit;
          fahrenheit = (int) (9.0/5.0 * celsius + 32);
         return fahrenheit;
       } // end method fahrenheit

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is wrong. You have an outer `if` statement that is only entered if the user does *not* enter three. So if you do, the `else` in the inner `if` will not be executed, and thus your message will never print:

```
//If you do enter three, it will skip over all of this:
if  ( choice != 3 ) {

     System.out.print( "Enter temperature: " ); // Display Enter Temperature
     temp = input.nextInt();  // Read Temperature


     if (choice == 1) {

         System.out.println( temp +  " Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius( temp ) + " Celsius ");
         System.out.println("");
     }

     else if (choice == 2 ) {
         System.out.println(temp + " Celsius is " +  toFahrenheit( temp ) + " Fahrenheit ");
         System.out.println("");

      } 
     else {   
         System.out.println("Program terminated ");   //  Display "Program terminated" if user entered 3
     }

}
```

You need to remove the outer `if`, or alternatively move the `else` block to after the outer `if`.

Comment: I moved the 'else' block after the outer if.  Now  it shows the message.
Thanks for your help.